# Target the same muscles twice in a day?

Tags: muscle, gym, weight-gain, muscle-gain

Would working the same muscle group - twice in the same day - cause *worthwhile* extra muscle fiber tearing to later gain mass? Or is this not worthwhile (the extra tearing is only marginal) given the long rest period between the two sessions (say morning and evening)? Why?

**Example:** working the upper and mid chest in the morning, and again in the evening, working to failure both sessions using high reps and moderate weight. There will be rest for that group for the next couple days, and proper diet is regularly followed.

---

Here are similar questions, but they are not the same:

- [How good/bad an idea is it to work out twice a day?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/how-good-bad-an-idea-is-it-to-work-out-twice-a-day)
- [How can I best recover for a second strength workout on the same day?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/how-can-i-best-recover-for-a-second-strength-workout-on-the-same-day)
- [Going to gym twice a day](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/going-to-gym-twice-a-day)

Comment: In my experience, the only people doing multi-day workouts are highly technical lifters (basically elite Olympic lifters) and guys on steroids. The first group isn't trashing themselves as much as needing a lot of coordination, and the latter group can have a ridiculously high repair rate.

Comment: Any advantage to it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've already hit the pros of this, as is expected.

The cons are going to revolve more around the restitution phase your muscles are going to need if you plan on making any gains at all from this.

You have to keep in mind that it's during rest that your muscles get bigger and stronger. So long as you allow for adequate rest, and adequate nutrition, the only thing left to do is give it a shot.

You're going to be learning first hand how *your* body will deal with this training modality, and it might be different from everyone else's. Be sure you listen to what your body is telling you. If one day you really, really don't feel like doing it, do something else, and give it a day or two. It might be a sign that you've overdone it.

And while the other questions might not have been exactly aligned with yours, the answers are pretty all-encompassing. For instance Dave Liepmann's answer here: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4776/8828

Comment: This response is thought out. Could it be phrased to be more objective and applicable in general? For example, would this indeed cause worthwhile added muscle fiber tearing given the long rest period between the two sessions? Or is this a poor plan, in general? Why?